# Does deleting the same data multiple times have a performance impact on a Cassandra cluster?

Tags: java, cassandra

If I need to perform an automated housekeeping task, and this is my query:
`delete from sample_table where id = '1'`

And, this scheduled query gets executed from multiple service instances.
Will this have a significant performance impact? What would be an appropriate way of testing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issuing multiple deletes for the same partition can have a significant impact on your cluster.

Remember that all writes in Cassandra (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) are inserts under the hood. Since Cassandra does not perform a read-before-write (with the exception of [lightweight transactions](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/architecture/guarantees.html#lightweight-transactions-with-linearizable-consistency)), issuing a `DELETE` will insert a tombstone marker regardless of whether the data exists or has already been deleted.

Every single `DELETE` you issue counts as a write request so depending on how busy your cluster is, it may have a measurable impact on its performance. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Erick's answer is pretty solid, but I'd just like to add that the time that you'll likely see performance issues is at read-time.  That's because doing a:

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE id='1';
```

...will read ALL of the times that the `DELETE` was written (tombstones) from the SSTable file.  The default settings on a table result in deleted data staying around for 10 days (to ensure proper replication) before they can be picked-up by compaction.

So figure out how many times that `DELETE` happens per key over a 10 day period, and that's about how many Cassandra will have to reconcile at read-time.